# Robot Framework finds text that does not exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, robotframework

I am validating some texts on a webpage . There are two piece of text that should be mutually exclusive  i,e only one of the texts should be visible at any time.

The element xpath=//*[@id="study_info"] actually retrieves the texts "No records available" or "Showing page x of x" based on the records and only one of this texts shows on the page. if there is no record, It shows "No record Available" otherwise it shows "showing Page x of x"

When I am trying to validate these in Robot Framework, It actually finds both text at a time, although I can see only one text. I do not know what is happening here.. The below code should fail as the texts are mutually exclusive and only one of the texts are visible. But it passes without any problem.

```
Page Should Contain    No records available
Page Should Contain    Showing page
Page Should Contain Element    xpath=//*[@id="study_info"]
```

The full code for the element is

```
"<div class="dataTables_info" id="study_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">No records available</div>
```

I need to understand what is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: Hint: inspect the HTML of the page through the HTML inspector (developer tools) of Firefox (or Chrome equivalent tool), and **not** the one provided by the server. JS stuffs may add elements that are not in the server provided HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the visualization (js) framework used, the text that is currently NOT visible may very well be in the HTML - the `div` having it to be hidden, put in a stack of possible values, etc., and to replace the visible element as needed.

The keyword `Page Should Contain` goes through the whole current html - it actually uses a locator `xpath=//*[contains(., %s)]`, where `%s` is the string you're after, and if any (hidden/overlaid/js source) element has the text, will return true.

To solve your particular case, I'd suggest a little bit different approach - get the text value of that element, and assert it's the expected one:

```
${locator}=    Set Variable    xpath=//*[@id="study_info"]
${current text}=      Get Text   ${locator}
Should Contain        ${current text}    Showing page
Should Not Contain    ${current text}    No records available    # and vice-versa
```